# Can't add new product to mongodb, having POST 500 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I'm having trouble on how adding new product to mongodb. I've done the registration side and it's working fine, and so as login. but when I'm adding product I received this message>

> POST http://localhost:5000/api/product/newProduct 500 (Internal Server Error)

I double-check my endpoint and I think im right.

```
dashboard.jsx
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router'

function Dashboard() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [categories, setCat] = useState("")
    const [error, seterror] = useState(false)
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [price, setprice] = useState(0)

    const handleCat = (e) => {
      setCat(e.target.value.split(','))
    }


    const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(categories,name,price)
        seterror(false)
        try {
          const prod = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/product/newProduct', {
          name, 
          categories,
          price
          })
          prod.data && navigate('/dashboard')
        } catch (error) {
          seterror(true)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() =>{
      const getProduct = async () =>{
        try {
          const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/product')
          setData(res.data)
        } catch (error) {
          
        }
      }
      getProduct()
    },[])

    //console.log(data)

    return (
        <form action="" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <div>
            <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Apple Airpods"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            name="desc"
            type="text"
            placeholder="description..."
            onChange={handleCat}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="addProductItem">
          <label>Price</label>
          <input
            name="price"
            type="number"
            placeholder="100"
            onChange={(e) => setprice(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button >Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
       
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const userRoute = require('./routes/auth')
const productRoute = require('./routes/product')

dotenv.config()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to Server')
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.use('/api/auth', userRoute)
app.use('/api/product', productRoute)

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Local Host is Running 5000')
})
```

productRoute.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const Product = require('../models/Product')

router.post('/newProduct', async (req, res) => {
  const newProduct = new Product(req.body)

  try {
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save()
    res.status(200).json(savedProduct)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find()
    res.status(200).json(products)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})
module.exports = router
```

schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    categories: { type: Array },
    img: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Comment: Just open `console` in your browser, `network tab` and double click on your `newProduct.js`. You will see actual error message

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your product Schema

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    categories: { type: Array },
    img: { type: String },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

Here categories is defined as type array and you are sending categories as string from frontend referencing your frontend code

const [categories, setCat] = useState("")

const prod = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/product/newProduct', {
name,
categories,
price
})

changing your schema categories type to string would solve the problem or you should send an array of categories to backend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).